# angular passing in controller variable to html custom filter parameter in ng repeat to be populated in a function so I can use in html later

Tags: html, angularjs

Currently, I have a controller, a filter file, and the html. Right now I have it so that in the html, I call a ng-repeat with a bunch of custom filters I created based off the filter im using for example:

`ng-repeat="p in persons = (person | toArray | filterHeight:height | filterAge:age | filterEthnicity:ethnicity)"`

what I want to add to this is basically only change the filterEthnicity function so that if I choose to filter by ethnicity, it will display the selected ethnicity group at the top of the list and displays the rest of the nonselected group below the filtered results. Basically an "unfiltered list". I see solutions where in the function I can change it to return objects or multiple arrays but that won't work for me because of all the other filters that I do with the 1 ng-repeat so I can only return an array.
I saw I can do something like this: filterEthnicity:ethnicity:unfiltered in the html
with the variable thats created in the controller $scope.unfiltered.

The problem i'm getting is that in the function I need to reset the value with each call so like unfiltered = [] but when I add that and print the value in the controller, it is always empty but in the function it is getting populated

in the controller I just created a variable like $scope.unfiltered = []

```
.filter('filterEthnicity', function() {
    return function(values, keys, unfiltered) {
        let filtered = [];
        unfiltered = []
        values.forEach(obj => {
            if (obj.person.ethnicity in keys) {
                filtered.push(obj);
                break;   
            }
            if (filt_list.indexOf(obj) === -1) {
                unfiltered.push(obj);
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    }
});
```

so in the code, when i print unfiltered in the filterEthnicity function, it is being populated but when I try printing $scope.unfiltered in the controller it is empty so when I try to use it in the html later on after the first ng-repeat like a simple second ng-repeat like

`ng-repeat="val in unfiltered"{{val.name}}`

it comes up as nothing

im mainly confused on why the $scope.unfiltered variable keeps coming up as empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create an Angular module and define a custom filter called startsWithLetter that filters an array of strings based on whether each string starts with a specified letter:

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).filter('startsWithLetter', function() {
    return function(items, letter) {
      var filtered = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if (item.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === letter.toLowerCase()) {
          filtered.push(item);
        }
      });
      return filtered;
    };
  });
```

The startsWithLetter filter takes two arguments: items, an array of strings to be filtered, and letter, the letter to filter by. The filter logic is straightforward: it iterates over each item in the items array, checks whether the first letter of the item matches the specified letter, and adds the item to the filtered array if it does.

Next, let's create an Angular controller that defines an array of strings and a variable to store the letter to filter by:

```
angular.module('demoApp').controller('DemoCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.items = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Date', 'Eggplant'];
    vm.letter = 'a';
});
```

The DemoCtrl controller uses the controllerAs syntax to define a variable vm that stores the controller's properties. The items property is an array of strings to be filtered, and the letter property stores the letter to filter by

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
  <label>Filter by letter:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.letter">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items | startsWithLetter:vm.letter">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The ng-repeat directive is used to iterate over the filtered vm.items array, passing the vm.letter variable to the startsWithLetter filter as the second argument

Comment: Hello, I believe my code already does what you are trying to do. I want to just add a new variable that I can use in my controller and html if that makes sense.

Comment: @Kyobuki use this example where i have added new variable in both controller and UI. 

`angular.module('demoApp').controller('DemoCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.title = 'Demo App'; // New variable
});`

----------------------------
`<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
  <h1>{{vm.title}}</h1> <!-- Use the new variable -->
</div>`